# Table width not adjusting to Resolution

Tags: html, css

It's like the table has a maximun width predefined but not sure what the issue is...

as you can see here the table is outside the outter div when the resolution is 1024x768

code:

outter div:

```
<div id="resourceGenerator_details_tab_div" class="tabsContent" style="float: none; height: auto; width: auto; display: block;" tabclick="" tabtext="Details" parenttabbarid="rg_tabBar" buttonid="rg_tabBar_resourceGenerator_details_tab_div_tab">
```

within this div I have:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of `auto`, use `100%`

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
```

make it to :

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

and make sure to add to `container` of table `width:100%;height:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Set `width:100%` in your outer `div` and `table`. This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `width:auto`  use `width:100%` in outer division. I tried it and it works.